# How to delete all hidden .swp files from terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, terminal, shell, globbing

How can I delete all .swp files? I tried `rm *.swp` but I got `rm: *.swp: No such file or directory`

```
rwxr-xr-x  16 teacher  staff    544 Jan 17 13:19 .
drwxr-xr-x  19 teacher  staff    646 Jan 16 12:48 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 teacher  staff  20480 Jan 17 09:48 .6-1-period-2.txt.swp
-rw-r--r--   1 teacher  staff  16384 Jan 17 09:05 .6-2-period-6.txt.swp
-rw-r--r--@  1 teacher  staff   6148 Jan 15 16:16 .DS_Store
-rw-r--r--   1 teacher  staff  12288 Jan 16 19:46 .grade8.txt.swp
-rw-r--r--   1 teacher  staff  11070 Jan 17 09:48 6-1-period-2.txt
```

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Unix, Linux, BSD, OSX, something else? Which version?

Answer (score 11):

What you wanted to do is

```
rm .*swp
```

The `*` does not match files starting with a `.` unless you [turn on dotglob](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html#The-Shopt-Builtin) (assuming you are using bash):

```
$ ls -la
-rw-r--r--   1 terdon terdon        0 Jan 17 05:50 .foo.swp
$ ls *swp  
ls: cannot access *swp: No such file or directory
$ shopt -s dotglob
$ ls *swp
.foo.swp
```

Answer (score 10):

If you say: files are hidden, then they start with a dot (.), so try:

```
find . -type f -name ".*.swp" -exec rm -f {} \;
```

With this approach you're looking for all hidden files into the current directory and subdirectories. If you want delete the hidden files of just the current directory, a simple `rm -f .*.swp` works ok

Comment: globstar is far simpler in bash 4+, `rm **/.*.swp` (with `shopt -s globstar` in a source bash file or in your current shell instance)

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

`find . -type f -name "*.swp" -exec rm -f {} \;`

```
-name "FILE-TO-FIND" : File pattern.
-exec rm -rf {} \; : Delete all files matched by file pattern.
-type f : Only match files and do not include directory names.
```

Comment: `-f` is force, just use it if you mean it

Comment: `rm -r` does only make sense for directories, since you are deleting files `-type f` it does not make sense