# Bash: Cleaning a folder and its subfolders of .log file

Tags: bash

How can i loop through a directory (and subdirectories) and delete every .log file? I want to use a bash script to clean my Minecraft server directory.

In Windows (batch) i use this line to loop: `for /r %%i in (*.log) do del /F %%i`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delete all hidden .swp files from terminal](https://superuser.com/questions/702913/how-to-delete-all-hidden-swp-files-from-terminal)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To print all `*.log` files recursively using the current directory as start directory (just to make sure these are the right files), use:

```
find . -name "*.log" -type f
```

And to delete them, use:

```
find . -name "*.log" -type f -exec rm {} +
```

Comment: i've used `find . -name "*.log" -type f -delete` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the `-delete` option is GNU specific and is not defined in the [posix standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/find.html) and thus not available in all `find` implementations. And be careful with this option. If you use it as the first option, you can easily delete the whole directory tree.